# How to send message to MSMQ using HTTP with Authentication using c#

Tags: c#, msmq

I am working on MSMQ. I have tried sending message to msmq using Http. I can send message to msmq using HTTP. But I have to restrict the user by Authentication. Can anyone help me to allow only specific user alone can send message to MSMQ. I have tried using checking the Authenticated Check box.But I cannot send the message. I have tried the Below code.

```
MessageQueue TestQueue = new MessageQueue();
System.Messaging.Message mesg = new System.Messaging.Message();      
TestQueue.Path=@"FormatName:DIRECT=HTTP://IPAddress/msmq/private$/Test";
TestQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
mesg.Label = "1000";
mesg.UseAuthentication = true;
TestQueue.Send(mesg);
TestQueue.Close();
```

Can anyone help me to send message to msmq using HTTP securly and authenticated?

Comment: Does the web server exist in the same domain/forest as the sending machine and user account?

Comment: Yes the server exist in the same sending machine.